# How can I assign properly a image to state and function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, assign

I am newbie. I want to create a function which uses a random number to change 3 images dynamically.

Example: if number > 5 = image1, if number > 10 = image2, if number > 15 = image3

I have tried some things for now but thats the best result I can get:[image]

```
random(min,max,x) {
    min = Math.ceil(5);
    max = Math.floor(20);
    return  x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

colormachine = () => {
if(this.random(this.props.x > 8))
{
    this.setState(state => ({color: green}));
};
}

render() {

    console.log(this.random());
    // console.log(this.colormachine());
```

`({ color: green })` is a

```
const green = { backgroundImage: "url(" + tirelogogreen + ")";
```

Comment: Post your code into the question itself, a picture of code is unreadable(not to mention can't copy it for testing purposes)

Comment: Sure, sorry for that. Fixed the question. @PatrickEvans

Comment: `state`'s should only contain data.  It should not contain styles and images.

Comment: Ahhh okay.. I have thought I could do this that way.. It makes that more complicated now

Answer (score 0):

The idea is your `state`s should only contain really simple data, nothing to do with styles.  For example, here I am storing a number.

```
const [myNum, setMyNum] = useState(0);
```

Then I have a button that updates the state:

```
<button onClick={() => setMyNum(Math.floor(Math.random() * 20))}>
```

Then, your component will decide what to do with it based on the number.

```
function Box(props) {
  // here i am getting different style based on what's being passed in
  const getStyle = myNum => {
    if (myNum > 4 && myNum < 10) return { backgroundColor: "green" };

    if (myNum > 10 && myNum < 15) return { backgroundColor: "blue" };

    if (myNum > 14) return { backgroundColor: "red" };

    return null;
  };

  return (
    <div className={"square"} style={getStyle(props.colorNum)}>
      <div className={"content"}>I'm a square.</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

For a working example, click here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-boilerplate-h2dbd